# Instanceof comparison with unreasonable result for OSGI bundle (Eclipse RCP)

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp

In an OSGI environement (Eclipse RCP) an object is compared with 'instanceof' with a class which should be obviously its parent class. Still the comparison returns 'false'. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason was: The super class compared with 'instanceof' was actually included in the build from another bungle version as the object at hand compared.